# mysql order by asc issue

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a application where we need to get the record order by asc but the value with zero record will be in last.
Have anyone help me regarding.
Here is my table structure

```
id      name        priority
1       abc             3
2       xyz             6
3       aaa             0
4       bbb             1
5       ccc             1
6       ddd             0
7       fff             2
```

want something like this

```
id      name        priority
1       bbb             1
2       ccc             1
3       fff             2
4       abc             3
5       xyz             6
6       aaa             0
7       ddd             0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY priority = 0, priority
```

**[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a583ff/1)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE PRIORITY > 0 ORDER BY PRIORITY) a 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE PRIORITY = 0
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e2bba/13)

Comment: In addition to being ugly, this method will also remove duplicate rows if they exist in source table.